# remove the space between words when the strings ends with a number in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

The length of my character is 30. 
I got to remove the last space from the string if it ends with a number .

**Eg.** 
`COADC Cathy & Ralph Ward Jr 73`                                                                                            should be `COADC Cathy & Ralph WardJr73`
and not `COADCCathy&RalphWardJr73`

Tried `regexp_like` to get the strings that end with numbers and then tried `trim()` and `replace()` spaces but did not work out. is there any other function?

Comment: Your example removes two spaces.

Comment: sorry . i missed to add . If length is 30 must remove 2 spaces from the end. If length is 29 must remove 1 space

Comment: @arsha, I updated my answer considering your comment.

Answer (score 1):

> remove the last space from the string if it ends with a number .

You can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(str, ' ([0-9]+$)', '\1')
from (select 'COADC Cathy & Ralph Ward Jr 73' as str from dual) x;
```

[Here][1] is a db<>fiddle.

Note that your example removes the last two spaces.  This example is following your description, not your example.  It also interprets "ends with a number" as "only digits follow the last space".

[1]: https://dbfiddle.uk/?> remove the last space from the string if it ends with a number .
rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=995e20520454ee8ffb8030ab156f7431

Comment: is it possible to replace last 2 spaces using regexp_replace()

Comment: if i just have to remove spaces from the string only considering the length irrespective of ending with a number. how will regexp_replace work ?

Comment: @arsha . . . I think you should ask a *new* question with a clearer definition and examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @s varchar(100)
set @s = 'COADC Cathy & Ralph Ward Jr 73'

set @s = case 
            when  isnumeric(right(@s, 1)) = 1 and len(@s) = 30 then reverse(STUFF(reverse(@s), PATINDEX('% %', reverse(@s)), 1, '')) 
            else @s 
        end

set @s = case 
            when  isnumeric(right(@s, 1)) = 1 and len(@s) = 29 then reverse(STUFF(reverse(@s), PATINDEX('% %', reverse(@s)), 1, '')) 
            else @s 
        end

select @s, len(@s)
```

When you run this query for the first time, it will remove one last space from all strings that are 30 characters long and end with a numbers.

After that simply change `len(@s) = 30` to `len(@s) = 29` and run it again.

It is not perfect solution, but I don't see any reason for it not to work.

Comment: i am using sql developer . it does not support stuff

Comment: @arsha I believe you could use `regexp_replace` part from Gordon's answer. Point is to run it twice, first time to remove last space from all 30s and make them 29s, and the second time to remove last space from all 29s.